# AWS Cron schedule expression

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron

I want to deploy function to AWS Lambda with using serverless framework in NodeJS/Typescript. Here is my serverless.yml:

```
service: backend

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack

provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-central-1
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: dev

functions:
  createDailyStatistics:
    handler: dist/services/schedules.scheduleDailyStatistics
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 0 * * *)
          enabled: true
```

can someone tell me, why after launch `serverless deploy` i got an error like this:

```
CREATE_FAILED: CreateDailyStatisticsEventsRuleSchedule1 (AWS::Events::Rule)
Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxx; Proxy: null)
```

My expression - `0 0 * * *` is a standard cron expression but AWS not handle this? I want to launch this functino on every day at midnight.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS uses the extended CRON expression format:

[image]

Please notice, there are 6 fields in the expression: `Minutes`, `Hours`, `Day of month`, `Month`, `Day of week` and `Year`.

In your case, you provide only 5 values. I'm guessing you were most likely using [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_*) to create your cron expression, meaning that you want an event to fire `At 00:00`. In that case, for AWS you would want to have something like this: `0 0 * * ? *`.

Comment: where is this screen from?

Comment: @BokuNoHeeeero AWS console -> Event Bridge -> Create new Scheduled Event.